# Why does the Buffer object have a capital B?

Tags: node.js

The only global object in Node that has a capitalised first letter is `Buffer`. It does not seem to be a constructor. Why the capital `B`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a constructor.

[`new Buffer`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.5/api/buffers.html#new_Buffer)